# CentOS 6 へ Python3.5 を SCL経由でインストールしたのですが、Apacheで利用するには？

Tags: python, centos

**CentOS 6 へ Python3.5 を SCL経由でインストールしたのですが、以前ビルドしたバージョンと競合(?)してしまい、うまくいきません**
・今、どういう状況でしょうか？

---

**今回Yumでインストールした Python3.5**

```
$ which python3.5
```

> /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python3.5

---

**以前ソースからビルドしたPython2系**
・使用していないためアンインストールしたいのですが、コピペでソースからビルドしたため、どうしたら良いか分からない

```
$ which python
```

> /usr/bin/python

---

**Pythonのバージョンを常に3.5へしたいのですが、**

```
$ python -V
```

> Python 2.6.6

下記コマンドを打つと一時的に3.5になるのですが、新規プロセスだと2.6と表示されます

```
$ source /opt/rh/rh-python35/enable
```

下記リンク先内容を試したのですが、効果ありませんでした
・[How do I enable python35 from Software Collections at login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910534/how-do-i-enable-python35-from-software-collections-at-login)

---

```
$ pip -V
```

> pip 7.1.0 from
>   /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)

---

```
$ sudo pip3.5 install mod_wsgi
```

> /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python3: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libpython3.5m.so.rh-python35-1.0: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory

---

**2017/5/11追記**
・[このページ](https://www.server-world.info/query?os=CentOS_7&p=python35)を参考に再度挑戦してみたのですが、「which python」した時点で2.6.6の方を見に行ってしまいます 
・まっさらな状態で一からやり直したいのですが、Python2.6.6を削除する方法はありますか？

**/usr/bin/python**
・下記ファイルを削除しても大丈夫でしょうか？

> python
>    python2 -> python
>    python2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS 6 の httpd で rh-python35 の `python` などを利用したいのであれば、`/etc/sysconfig/httpd` に次のような文を追加して `httpd` サービスを再起動するだけかと。

```
source scl_source enable rh-python35
```

`sudo` 経由の場合は呼び出し元の環境変数のいくつかは引き継がれないので、`sudo` した先で有効化すればよいでしょう。

```
$ sudo sh -c 'source scl_source enable rh-python35; pip install mod_wsgi'
```

`source scl_source enable rh-python35` は、指定した SCL パッケージを利用可能とするために、いくつかの環境変数を設定しているだけです。以下は実行前後の環境変数の違いを出力する例です。

```
$ bash -c 'diff <(env|sort) <(source scl_source enable rh-python35;env|sort)'
5a6
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64
9c10,12
< PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
---
> MANPATH=/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/share/man:
> PATH=/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
> PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/pkgconfig
20a24,25
> XDG_DATA_DIRS=/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share
> X_SCLS=rh-python35
```

Comment: 「/etc/sysconfig/httpd」へ追加後、「$ sudo service httpd restart」してみたのですが、「$ python -V」は「2.6.6」のままでした。「2.6.6」を削除したいのですが、何か良い方法はあるでしょうか？

Comment: 親子関係にもないプロセスの環境変数がほかに影響しないのは当然なので、自明です、としか…。Python 3.5 をシェルから利用したいなら、どうにかして `source scl_source enable rh-python35` を実行するようにしてください。それから CentOS 6 の /usr/bin/python は OS に必須とも言えるものなので、置き換えたり削除しては駄目ですよ。

Comment: Python 3.5 をシェルから利用したい件については、aliasを設定したので、3.5で利用できるようになりました。本題の件は、libpython3.5m.so.rh-python35-1.0がない、とログ表示されます。確認してみたら「/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64」ディレクトリ以下に確かにファイルはあるので、それを読み込めたらうまくいくと思うのですが。「source scl_source enable rh-python35」を「/etc/sysconfig/httpd」に記述すると、http実行時に読み込まれ「LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64」が指定される、という意味でしょうか？

Comment: はい、そのはずです(未確認)。詳細は `/etc/init.d/httpd` を参照。ちなみに、CentOS 7 は systemd なので、`/etc/sysconfig/httpd` にシェルスクリプトは書けないので、同じ方法は使えません。